# How to delete DynamoDB multiple key's?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

- I have dynamodb table
- I need to remove 2 keys(type, code) from all the items, and update another key into each item(msg)
- id is the partitionkey
- How to delete the attribute `type` from each item if my type is only Fail?
- There is no condition for `code` it should be deleted from each item

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('test-table')
result = table.scan()
scan_response = result.copy()
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in result:
     result = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=result['LastEvaluatedKey'])
     scan_response['Items'].extend(result['Items'])

for each in scan_response['Items']:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': each['id']
        },
        AttributeUpdates={
            'msg': {
                'Value': ''
            },
        }
    )
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': each['id']
        },
        UpdateExpression='REMOVE type, code'
    )
```

Above code is working fine, I am able to delete type and code and update msg  from every item

Documentation saying i cant do the operation at one shot(UpdateExpression, AttributeUpdates)

Comment: By "if my type is only Fail", I think you mean you want to conditionally update only those items whose `type` attribute has the value "Fail". Note: the word 'key' means something very specific and is not the same thing as 'attribute'. You appear to be trying to update/delete attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your update expression to include both setting the msg.Value property and removing type and code:

```
UpdateExpression='REMOVE type, code SET msg.Value = ""'
```

Comment: How to delete the attribute type from each item if my type is only Fail?There is no condition for code it should be deleted from each item.

Comment: If you want a condition expression, you need to make two Update requests, one of which has a ConditionExpression. You can wrap these in a TransactWrite if you want the operation to be atomic.

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294085/how-to-delete-multiple-items-from-dynamodb-list