# How to delete items from dynamodb list

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

- listofvalues to remove = [1,2,3]
- myList from dynamodb = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
- Do i need to loop every single item find the index and remove
- Is there any better approach
- Gone through link [Add or remove an entry from a List type attribute in a DynamoDB table item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item)

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('myowntable')
response = []
response_table = table.get_item(Key={'id': '19'})
        if 'Item' in response_table and response_table['Item']:
            response.append(response_table['Item'])

listofvalues = [1,2,3]
for i in listofvalues:
    id_index_delete = str(response[0]['myList'].index(i))
    query = "REMOVE myList[" + id_index_delete + "]"
    table.update_item(
                    Key={
                        'id': '19'
                    },
                    UpdateExpression=query
                )
```

Comment: Your update can include multiple removes.

Comment: @hunterhacker Can you post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [remove multiple items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) from a list in a signle operation with an update expression like `REMOVE myList[0], myList[2]`.  Here's one way to do it using boto3:

```py
id = 'a1'
response_table = table.get_item(Key={'id': id})
response = response_table.get('Item', {}).get('myList', [])
listofvalues = [1,2,3] # remove these items from myList

items_to_remove = [f'myList[{response.index(x)}]' for x in listofvalues if x in response ]
query = "REMOVE " +  ", ".join(items_to_remove)

if len(items_to_remove):
  table.update_item(Key={'id': id}, UpdateExpression=query)
```

Comment: Is below code is correct its working fine `oldlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`   
`newlist = [1,2,3]`   
`newlist_remove = [v for v in oldlist if v not in newlist]`  
`table.update_item(Key={ 'id': '19' }, AttributeUpdates={'myList':{'Value': newlist_remove} })`

Comment: @sim Yes, with two warnings: (1) For larger lists you will [consume more WRU](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/#DynamoDB_detailed_feature_pricing) by re-writing them, leading to higher cost at scale; and (2) `AttributeUpdates` is a legacy parameter.  Use `UpdateExpression` instead.

Comment: Must I get the List column first and then update it? Isn' there a way to just query this directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn your list into a map, you can then delete items based on the map key and do all deletes in one operation.

Old: `[1,2,3]`

New: `{“1”:1,”2”:2,”3”:3}`